# Count and Mark TRUE if Range in a Single Row Contains 3 or More Instances of TRUE

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So, I'm wanting to count the number of cells in a row (U5:X5) that contain TRUE, and if the range contains 3 or more instances of TRUE, I want to mark the cell TRUE, showing that yes, there are 3 or more instances of TRUE in the range.

What I have so far is not working...

```
=IF(COUNTIF(U5:X5,"TRUE") >= 3,"TRUE","")
```

Here's a [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZMYVU16AVijLfEoo7d6ednjz5jifeZv6IykI4tHwa_s/edit?usp=sharing) that you can edit.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the quotation marks around the TRUEs in your formulas and entered the following in J2:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,MMult(N(F2:I),{1;1;1;1})>=3))
```

Comment: when I plugged the formula in, my Google Sheet went from having only 30 rows displaying, to having over 12,000 rows. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: if the range starts on row 2, *don't* insert the formula below row 2.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
=COUNTIF(A5:F5,TRUE)>=3
```

[image]

Comment: For me, it's still showing FALSE when I paste in that formula. Let me see if I can post a sample spreadsheet.

Comment: @user14915635 then you have text in cells. Try ```=COUNTIF(A5:F5,"'TRUE")>=3```

Comment: Ok that worked, how could I make it automatically go down the column? I'm pretty familiar with using arrayformula, but it's not working for me. Here's what I have =arrayformula(if(A2:A="",,countif(U5:X5,"'TRUE")>=3))

Comment: @user14915635 use: ```=arrayformula(if(A5:A="",,countif(U5:X,"'TRUE")>=3)) ```

Comment: unfortunately, that marks them all as true. I've read somewhere that you can't include COUNTIF in an ARRAY without using MMULT or TRANSPOSE or something else, but can't get it to work with my version of COUNTIF. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user14915635 of course, my fault, then try: ```=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A5:A),COUNTIF(IF(U5:X="TRUE",ROW(U5:X)),ROW(U5:X))>=3,))```

Comment: Hmmm, tried that, but it's marking a row that has 3 TRUE's in it as FALSE. I created a Google Sheet with the sample formula in it. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZMYVU16AVijLfEoo7d6ednjz5jifeZv6IykI4tHwa_s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @user14915635 It is correct, because in ```H3``` you have bool value not text.